# MDX Calculation Tab

Tags: ssas

I am new to SSAS and I am trying to write a query in ssas caluculation tab that will show all customers (customername) and items ordered (ItemName) in last 40 days. I am not sure is calculation tab the best option to do this.

I have got only one measure VOLUME and dimension attributes (customername,itemname,officename,shipdate ...) I have got also Date Hierarchy with Year->Q->Month->Date.

I have got this statement that gives me netvolume for specific itemname in last 40 days, but what i am looking for is all customers and items ordered in last 40 days. I do not need measure.  ( this 40 days might change to 20 or 60 days)

SELECT 
{ [Measures].[NET VOLUME]} ON COLUMNS,
FILTER
(
  {[CUBENAME].[SHIPDATE].&[2018-03-23T00:00:00]:[CUBENAME].[SHIPDATE].&[2018-05-01T00:00:00]},
  [CUBENAME].[ITEMNAME].&[11# RPC 6411]
) ON ROWS
FROM[CUBENAME]

Answer (score 0):

Try using named query in the DSV and filter based on the date field.